# ReadTimeoutException on ReactiveElasticsearchClient of Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-data-elasticsearch, reactor-netty

With the default ReactiveElasticsearchClient I am getting ReadTimeoutExceptions on loadtest with jmeter when trying to index a document. I´m indexing 1 document per user. 500 concurrent user. loop count 20.

Elasticsearch cluster, the application and jmeter is all run on same machine (localhost).

Any idea why I´m getting these Exceptions? Do I need to configure the underlying WebClient of ReactiveElasticsearchClient differently?

Reference StackOverflow question for broder context: [Why is my Spring MVC (Tomcat NIO, RestHighLevelClient) outperforming Webflux (Netty, ReactiveElasticsearchClient) on load test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560288/why-is-my-spring-mvc-tomcat-nio-resthighlevelclient-outperforming-webflux-ne)

ReactiveElasticsearchClient:

```
@Configuration
public class ReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration{


@Override
@Bean
public ReactiveElasticsearchClient reactiveElasticsearchClient() {
    final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo(getHostAndPort()) //
            .build();
    return ReactiveRestClients.create(clientConfiguration);

}
```

ReadTimeoutException:

````
io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null
08:50:53.010 [reactor-http-nio-8] ERROR reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1232 - | onError(org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: nested exception is io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException)
08:50:53.010 [reactor-http-nio-8] ERROR reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1232 - 
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: nested exception is io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:137)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST http://localhost:9200/person_index/_doc?refresh=true&timeout=1m [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:137)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:70)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:224)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:273)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:413)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:250)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:97)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:189)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onUncaughtException(HttpClientConnect.java:359)
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onUncaughtException(ReactorNetty.java:631)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:213)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:476)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:230)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundError(FluxReceive.java:442)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundError(ChannelOperations.java:467)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:127)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.readTimedOut(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:98)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.channelIdle(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:90)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$ReaderIdleTimeoutTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:504)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$AbstractIdleTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:476)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null```
````

Comment: running the client, the service and elasticsearch on the same host for performance tests makes this quite unpredictable. There are three processes that need CPU and memory at the same time, so they are influencing their performance. Can you uprovide a minimal runnable project with the reactive code?